# Getting generalized forces and moments from virtual power method

Tags: forces, energy, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, work

I have a confusion when applying the Lagrangian method to calculate the equations of motion of a rigid body. I don't understand at what (physical) point the generalized moments should be calculated, if such a concept exists.

The Lagrangian method can be derived through the method of virtual powers, which dictates the following:
$$\sum_{system} W^* =\sum_{system}\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}(P)} \boldsymbol{v^*(P)} + \sum_{system}\boldsymbol{F(P)} \boldsymbol{v^*(P)} = 0$$

This can be expressed in terms of the components of the generalized inertia force and the components of the generalized force.

$$ \mathcal{F_i}^*+F_i^* = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ where: \\
\mathcal{F_i}^*= \sum_{system}\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}(P)} \boldsymbol{b_i(P)} \\
F_i^*= \sum_{system}\boldsymbol{F(P)} \boldsymbol{b_i(P)}$$

For holonomic systems where $\boldsymbol{v^*(P)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\boldsymbol{b_i(P)}\dot{q_i}^*$  after some calculations, we can arrive at the following:

$$\mathcal{F_i}^*=-\left[ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q_i}} - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i}\right]$$
Which leads to:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q_i}} - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i} = F_i^*$$
If the components of the generalized force are separated into conservative and non-conservative parts, the Lagrangian can be obtained. However, for now, I am interested in having the equation in this form.

The first thing that strikes me is that this is initially defined only for a system of particles, not for a rigid body. I understand that the rigid body emerges from the system of particles, but the only way I can think of introducing the concept of a rigid body is by applying the method of virtual powers to the theorems of linear momentum and angular momentum.

From this point forward, these are my own reasoning which I'm not sure if they are valid or not, but I have a gut feeling they lead somewhere.

In this case, I consider a virtual angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\Omega^*(Solid)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\boldsymbol{c_i(P)}\dot{q_i}^*$ and apply the angular momentum theorem at any point H of the solid.

$$\sum_{system} W^* =  \sum_{system}\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}(P)} \boldsymbol{v^*(P)} + \sum_{system}\boldsymbol{F(P)} \boldsymbol{v^*(P)}+\sum_{system}\boldsymbol{\mathcal{M}}_H^{d'Alembert}\boldsymbol{\Omega^*(Solid)} + \sum_{system}M_H\boldsymbol{\Omega^*(Solid)} = 0 $$

This equation as it is, I'm not sure if it's correct, but I believe all I'm doing is combining the virtual power of the entire system due to forces and moments. Somehow, it makes sense to me.

Analogously to the case of a system of particles, I think the sum of the components of the generalized forces and moments of inertia will be this:
$$\mathcal{F_i}^* + \mathcal{M_i}^* = -\left[ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q_i}} - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i}\right]$$
Where now the kinetic energy is not that of a system of particles but that of a rigid body. With this, the equation can also be stated as:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q_i}} - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i} = F_i^*+M_i^* $$

At this point, I raise the question of whether my reasoning is erroneous, where the error might be if so. Secondly, if this is correct, where is the kinetic energy of the rigid body calculated? Because according to the above, the point of calculating the kinetic energy must be the same as the point of calculating the moments affecting the system. Therefore, if I calculate the moments at one point or another, the components of the generalized moments will be different.

I have written quite a bit as it's all I know at the moment, and I want to provide some perspective on the mess I'm currently in.

These concepts are taken from 'Agulló, J. (2000) '[Mecánica de la partícula y del sólido rígido](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1COjYb_g-FrxZm1XWhbGhD7laHo1Ogy6F/view?usp=sharing)' regarding the topics of Lagrange equations and the method of virtual powers.

Comment: In the Lagrangian formalism, the kinetic energy $T$ is calculated in terms of the generalized coordinates $q_i$ and their time derivatives $\dot{q_i}$, but it doesn't depend on the point where it's calculated. When you're calculating moments of inertia $\mathcal{M_i}^*$ they should be calculated for the point where angular momentum is being considered, so it ensures consistency between the kinetic energy and the moments of inertia.

Comment: The $\mathcal{M_i}^*$ isn't the moment of inertia. Is the way I named the generalized moment. As the Lagrangian method have generalized forces as the non conservative ones, I described the generalized moments or torques. I understand the part that the angular momentum and the tensor of inertia needs to be calculated in the same point, but what I don't understand is in what point do I need to calculate the external moments or torques for later applying the virtual power (or work) method.

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad, thanks for letting me know. Regarding the point at which you calculate the external moments or torques, I'd say that it depends on the specific problem and the context in which you're analyzing the motion of the rigid body. You should choose the point where you are interested in analyzing the motion or dynamics of the rigid body and it could be the center of mass, a fixed point on the body, or any other point of interest for your analysis (making sure that there's consistency also with the point where you calculate the kinetic energy).

Comment: This question started with a rigid double pendulum in which I wanted to introduce a input torque in the base (N point). As I considered all restriction forces (for academic purposes) after applying virtual work in N there were restriction moments that I needed to calculate, and I didn't want to. If I calculate the moments in the joint of both pendulums those restriction moments are zero. What I understand by your answer is that if I want that joint point, I need to calculate the tensor of inertia in that point for the kinetic energy. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to calculate the external moments or torques at the joint point of the double pendulum, you should calculate the tensor of inertia relative to that point for the kinetic energy. If you have any other doubt, please let me know :)